# Use Select option as search with dynamic fields

Tags: php, html, sql

I am making a site linked with a database. It sorts transactions for budgeting reasons. For the store search section, I have a `select` drop down menu. I have linked up the data so that the drop down only shows stores that are in the database and automatically adds them as they change dynamically.

My issue is that I need a way to actually use the `select` options as search terms. Here is the initial page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Output 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Required Output 1</h1>
<h2>Transaction Search</h2>
<form action="output1out.php" method="get">
    Search Store:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="StoreName">
    <br/>
    <input name="Add Merchant" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$connection = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username,$db_password, $db_database);

if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    die("Database Connection Failed: ".mysqli_connect_error()." (".mysqli_connect_errno().")");
};

$query = "SELECT * from PURCHASE";
//echo $query;
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if(!$result) {
    die("Database Query Failed!");
};

$distinct = "SELECT DISTINCT StoreName FROM PURCHASE";
$distinctResult = mysqli_query($connection,$distinct);
if(!$result) {
    die("Database Query Failed!");
};

echo '<select name="search_string" />'."\n";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($distinctResult)){
    echo '<option value="'.$row["StoreID"].'">';
    echo $row["StoreName"];
    echo '</option>'."\n";
};
echo '</select>'."\n";

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Here is the output page.

```
<?php
$transaction = $_REQUEST["StoreName"];
require_once 'login.php';

$connection = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username,$db_password, $db_database);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM PURCHASE WHERE StoreName LIKE '%".$transaction."%'";
$result = $connection->query($sql);
?>

Purchases Made From <?php echo $transaction ?>
<table border="2" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th width="15%">Item Name</th>
        <th width="15%">Item Price</th> 
        <th width="15%">Purchase Time</th>
        <th width="15%">Purchase Date</th>
        <th width="15%">Category</th>
        <th width="15%">Rating</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    // output data of each row
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<table border="2" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['ItemName']; ?></td>
        <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['ItemPrice']; ?></td>
        <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['PurchaseTime']; ?></td>
        <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['PurchaseDate']; ?></td>
        <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['Category']; ?></td>
        <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['Rating']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

I can get regular typing search to work but I can't think of a way to search using the same method. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you referring to the `search_string` drop down? Are you wanting to substitute that for the  `StoreName` text input or are you wanting to add both so the query includes both criteria??

Comment: I want to use the drop down instead of the text input. Text input is just there to ensure that the SQL statement works properly but will be removed later.

Comment: So have you just tried moving the select up into the form and replacing the text field? You'd have to rename it of course.

Comment: What I'm really asking is how to call the correct entry from the select tool using the method I'm using. The select I'm using is being called from in the php with echos which is why I'm not sure how to call it the same way

Comment: You don't know how to integrate the php echo stuff with html? Sorry, I am still not 100% sure what you are really saying.

Comment: On a side note, you will probably help yourself a lot by wrapping things in functions. It will clean up your code and make things easier to read.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear. Because I am populating the select fields dynamically from a database column, i do not have a set number to pick an index from. I need to somehow save the text for the search without directly calling it.